# org.apache canot be resolved in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
```

Please anyone tell me what does this error tells. and how to solve it.

Comment: Add corresponding jars to lib/classpath.

Comment: what is the error that you are getting? Please provide more information.

Comment: import org.apache cannot  be resloved..iam getting this error. which jar files i need to add?

Comment: @user3148359 if my answer is helpful you can select my answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope you would get the jar files from distribution files.

Here is the link [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/download.html)

Answer (score 0):

Reason for the error is Your program cannot find `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;` class so for this you to download jar containing `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*` and then set your classpath.

[Here is the link to download jar](http://mavenhub.com/c/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook/jar)